# Avoid duplication of values for certain fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I created a view for a customer to show product sold in a specific area but along with that it give the qty on hand, on order etc...

The data looks like this:

```
ProdID Area QtySold QtyonHand
-----------------------------
ABC1    B0     5        12
ABC1    AK     20       12
ABC1    BT     3        12
----------
```

If possible, I would like to view it as below:

```
ProdID Area QtySold QtyonHand
-----------------------------
ABC1    B0     5        12
ABC1    AK     20       0 (or blank)
ABC1    BT     3        12
----------
```

I know how to use the group by function to sum the qty on hand, but the duplication of the QtyOnHand causes certain reports to be incorrect.

Is there a way to only give this value once per code? (I am no expert in sql, I know basics.)

Thank you

(sorry - new to stackoverflow - finding my feet here)

Comment: Can you give us an example of desired output?

Comment: This is a classic example of where you should separate out your data into separate tables. You should have the Products in one table, with the QtySold and QtyonHand fields, and the Area field in another table. Then you create a many-to-many relationship using a further table to map the relationship between the two. Then when you write your query, you won't have the duplication

Comment: Thank you. The area and QtySold comes from the same table, an Invoice table. Would the many-to-many still work?